# Extracting list of values from lotus notes fields

Tags: lotus-notes

I am migrating a Lotus Notes database to SQL Server using the LN java API. While traversing through each LN field in the documents I find all tabular info have field names like fld, fld_1, fld_2 etc where fld represents the name of a column and the numbering scheme is to take care of each individual row. Is there an simple way of extracting these info as arrays using the LN java API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no simple way, or more specifically, no way that Lotus Notes will help you with the task.  Lotus Notes is a 'flat-file' database and each document is allowed to have any number of items (columns) within it.

Although a Lotus Notes form might display data in a tabular format using a table or layout region, the document (record) that holds that data is simply like a single row of a SQL table, and there are no ways to logically group items of that document, for example, to relate all the fld_ items together.

My suggestions is to use whatever data structure you find convenient to get the data from the items into SQL.  That might be an array or a custom object that can then be saved to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Well "simple" can be an ambiguous term.

If you haven't solved this problem yet. You can write a method that loops around and grabs each field like this:

```
import lotus.domino.*;
....
public static void main(String[] arg) {

    for(int i=1 ;i<MAX_FIELD;i++) {
        Item itm = doc.getFirstItem("field_"+String.valueOf(i));
        if (itm != null) {
            // if it's a multi-value field.
            Vector v = item.getValues();
            // do other stuff here with the values.
         };
    }
}
```

You'll need to make sure you import the appropriate NotesJava API's in your project.

Remember that each field on a document is effectively and array with 1 or more values. Those fields ("field_1", "field_2", etc) were defined arbitrarily by a developer. This is a common practice to emulate table-like data structures. Usually the fields represent columns not rows. But accessing the field in this way using the "item" object should give you access to the data.